# Installation and Configuration

Tags: oracle, installation, configuration, timesten

Oracle TimesTen direct connectivity mode is the preferred mode of connection for the lowest possible latency. How can I connect using that and are there any limitations?

Answer (score 0):

Direct mode is the fastest connectivity option. In order to use direct mode the following criteria must be met:

- The application must be running on the same host (physical or VM), or in the same pod (Kubernetes) as the TimesTen database.
- The OS user under which the application is running must be a member of the TimesTen users OS group (https://docs.oracle.com/database/timesten-18.1/TTINS/ovwreqts.htm#TTINS916 ).
- The TimesTen environment variables have been set correctly.
- You have configured a suitable direct mode DSN in the TimesTen instance's sys.odbc.ini file. This type of DSN is needed in order to setup the database in the first place, so likely you will already have one defined.
  Direct mode can be used with all supported APIs.